# Delete the value in the database if the file does not exist

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I'am scanning a folder like this

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var folders = di.GetDirectories().ToList().Select(d => d.Name);

var files = di.GetFiles();
```

I'am saving the filenames to the database and can get all the files from the database like this

```
var image = db.Images.ToList()
```

I want to delete the row from the database if the file does not exists

I'am trying something like this but it's not working

```
var myimages = db.Images.ToList();
foreach (var img in myimages) {

var fileExist = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals(img));

if (fileExist == null)
{
Delete from database
}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: No, I get nothing if I write "Debug.WriteLine("Excist: " + fileExist);", or just "Excist: " in the debug.

Comment: @Xtreme can you show the defenition of images class and do you use any ORM like entity framework. Show your deletion code

Answer (score 0):

If you have id for each row in your database, you can try this :

```
var myimages = db.Images.ToList();
string ids = "";
foreach (var img in myimages) {

    var fileExist = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals(img));

    if (fileExist != null)
        ids+=img.id.ToSting()+",";

}

if(ids=="")
   return

ids = ids.Remove(ids.Length-1,1);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from [Images] where id not in ("+ids+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

should be your dbobject.yourtable.remove(img);

Comment: hmm but this is exactly what the guy below me just said...maybe i didnt come across correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(fileexist == null)
{
   db.Images.Remove(img);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple question,Hope this works. Good luck

I think your Image class contains a name field if so do this way. otherwise just modify this. Just ask if you have doubt

```
        var myimages = db.Images.ToList();    
        foreach (var img in myimages) 
        {
            var fileExist = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals(img.name));

            if (fileExist == null)
            {
               db.Images.Remove(img);
               db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```